# Deleting a row from tableView and coredata

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am retrieving the data from coredata and showing it in tableview. If the user clicks on a row it will navigate to another view (say view 2).

Now, I want to delete a row from the tableview as well as from coredata. I used a code with which, I am able to delete the row. But, when I go to view 2 and come back the record is back there. ( Its getting deleted from coredata but the row and its data is still there until, I reload the view).

This is the code i used.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) 
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"App" message:@"Sorry the Item Cannot be deleted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `reloadData` once deleted,

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
  {
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
   [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
   NSError *error;
   if (![context save:&error]) 
     {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Xpense Tracker" message:@"Sorry the Item Cannot be deleted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        alertView release];
     }
   [YOURTABLEVIEW reloadData];
  }
```

**EDITED:** it is working fine now. Try this way

```
Step 1:

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

Step 2:

update your 
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self; // with this
}

step 3:

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext * context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        NSError * error;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Deletion Error");
        }
    }

}

Step 4:

include NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method 
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [YOURTABLEVIEW reloadData];
}
```

Comment: data is deleted but the row and accessory type is visible.

Comment: once deleted,fetch again and reload the tableView with new data.

Comment: I did it and swipe to delete is working now.but when i click on the edit button where all the rows get a small minus symbol.if i tap on delete there the app is getting stuck there.(not a crash).

Comment: @Chandu Have you found solution for your Question?

Answer (score 1):

`NSManagedObjectContext` need to save once you deleted.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        NSError *error;
        [context save:&error] //add this line

        if (![context save:&error]) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Xpense Tracker" message:@"Sorry the Item Cannot be deleted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];

        }
    }

    }
```

check with this..

Comment: when you reload the views only it displays perfect right..? so successfully deleted the object from core data. how did you come back view2 to view1..If you are using remove from superview,where you needs to put custom delegate and reload the table view

Comment: if i am on view1 the delete is working fine but if i go to view 2 and coming back to view 1 then its not working.i am nt using remove from super view.i am just using the basic navigation controller.

Comment: you need to delete NSManaged object when you go to view2.so when user clicks pushing to next view using navigation controller na, add this deleting code into didSelectRowAtIndexpath

Comment: doesnt it delete the row i am selecting

Comment: yeah..am little bit confusing that where exactly the problem is. If its in core data deletion or proper place to reload the table view

Comment: proper place to reload the table view.

Comment: Have you tried to reload the table view using custom delegate from where you pop out or coming back to view1?

Answer (score 0):

change your table and details relations based on your requirement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSManagedObject *selectedOrder = [selectedOrderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Order *orderInstance = (Order *) selectedOrder;
        numberOfRows = [[orderInstance.detailRelation allObjects]count];

        NSString *deletedItem;

        deletedItem = (orderInstance.optionName == nil) ? [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ deleted successfully",orderInstance.menuName] :  [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ %@ deleted successfully",orderInstance.optionName , orderInstance.menuName];

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:selectedOrder];        
        if([self performSaveInMemoryObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]){

           // [self.tableview reloadData];
            [common ShowAlert:deletedItem andMessage:@""];
            [selectedOrderArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }
        [self fetchRecords];
     //   NSLog(@"count... %d",[selectedOrderArray count]);
        [tableview reloadData];

    }
}
```